# package installation from Github doesn't work (maybe problem with .egg file)

Tags: python, github, package, site-packages

Can't get Pycharm to recognize an installed package from GitHub.

Using GitHub desktop i've downloaded a depository 'mesa-reader' and ran inside the repository:

```
python setup.py install
```

Then, i tried to add this package in Pycharm to the project interpreter and got [image: this error]

This got me to look in the site-packages directory which got an .egg file (not directory) from the install  When i installed 'Django' (for example) it installed a directory and i don't know which case is the common one.

I tried to unzip the .egg file but it made no change.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
I unzipped the .egg file and copied it's content to the site-packages folder of my project.
only problem is I fear that in a new project i will have to redo this process.